# How do I apply a discount price for every 5th item bought?

Tags: asp-classic

My code is in classic ASP, but as long as you can give me some tips or algorithm in any language (PHP, JavaScript, Java), I will be able to make it out in classic ASP.

I have managed to sort my recordset into descending order by the price. More expensive items come first. Currently, I loop through the recordset and put each item into a multidimensional array.

```
Do While NOT RS.EOF
    arrBought(itemcount, 0) = RS("ItemID")
    arrBought(itemcount, 1) = RS("Price")
    arrBought(itemcount, 2) = RS("QuantityBought")

    RS.MoveNext
    itemcount = itemcount + 1
Loop
```

But how do I amend the above loop to allocate a 20% discount for every 5th item bought by the quantity?

Let's say, the customer bought the following items. The recordset will have the following data:

ItemID: A005,
Price: 100,
QuantityBought: 2

ItemID: A001,
Price: 80,
QuantityBought: 2

ItemID: A006,
Price: 60,
QuantityBought: 5

How do I loop through that recordset and create the following array?

```
arrBought(0, 0) = "A005"
arrBought(0, 1) = 100
arrBought(0, 2) = 2

arrBought(1, 0) = "A001"
arrBought(1, 1) = 80
arrBought(1, 2) = 2

arrBought(2, 0) = "A006"
arrBought(2, 1) = 48 '20% discounted
arrBought(2, 2) = 1

arrBought(3, 0) = "A006"
arrBought(3, 1) = 60
arrBought(3, 2) = 4
```

Comment: I think the best thing to do here would be to break out the trusty pencil and paper and work out how you would do it if someone were to give *you* the task to execute, instead of the computer. Going from that to pseudocode, then to actual code, shouldn't be *too* bad after.

Comment: Trust me, I have been doing that too... But can't really figure that out. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Actually, never mind. Give me a bit...

Comment: Quick question, will each item show up exactly once in the record set, or can it show up once and then appear later in the same program?

Comment: @user3580294 Each item will only show up once in the recordset. Anyway, note that it will be more complicated, if the QuantityBought were bigger, because every 5th item will have the discount. Example, if A006 QuantityBought were 10, then will have 2 units at $48, and 8 units at $60.

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! OK, let's split this into two questions. First: If I told you that a customer bought `x` items (say, 22) with ID `A006`, how would you determine how many of those items would have a discount? And second: If I told you that the price of those items were `y` (insert local currency) (say, 45), how would you determine the price of the discounted items?

Comment: (trust me, this will eventually get somewhere, and hopefully will be better than someone handing you a solution). And this isn't complicated at all, since each item shows up exactly once. It's math!

Comment: First question. Use division by 5 and modulo by 5. The discounted price would be price x 0.8 (20% off).

Comment: Well, you technically don't need modulus -- regular `int` division (aka round down) will do the trick just fine. But otherwise that's right!

Comment: So if you know that given `x` items `x / 5` of them will be discounted, how many of them will not be discounted? This should be the final piece needed.

Comment: That will be x - (x/5)

Comment: So given `x` items, you know `x/5` are discounted, and `x - (x / 5)` are not. You also know that the normal price is `y` and the discounted price is `y * 0.8`. So given this, do you think you can implement some additional logic in your loop to accomplish what you want?

Comment: Hint: you will probably need an `if` statement or something of the sort to determine whether you need to use the next element of the array for discounted items, and if you do, to start the next item at the right place

Comment: Problem is, I need to take account of other items' quantities too. In the example above, A005 doesn't get any discount, nor does A001. But A006 gets 1 unit discount because when sorted in "price DESC", it has a 5th item. How do I handle this logic?

Comment: Ohhhh, I thought you meant 5th item per item. Are you asking for 5th item "globally"?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being clear. Yes, every 5th item globally.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry for wasting your time... Luckily, the solution isn't much different -- make `x` a counter, instead of making it equal to the quantity of items, and in this case you would indeed need to use `x % 5`. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's a little hard for me to really work that out... any algorithm please?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a crack at it. As user3580294 was walking you through, it's basically a matter of accounting for the units that will be regularly priced and those that will be discounted.

```
dim intItemCount
dim intQtyBought
dim strItemID
dim curPrice
dim intQtyToDiscount
dim intDiscountSwitch 
intItemCount = 0
intDiscountSwitch = 0
Do While NOT RS.EOF
    strItemID = RS("ItemID")                        'More efficient than repetitively referencing the RS
    curPrice = RS("Price")
    intQtyBought = RS("QuantityBought")
    intQtyToDiscount = 0                                'Set to 0 each record
    intDiscountSwitch = intDiscountSwitch + intQtyBought
    if intDiscountSwitch >= 5 then                      'Need to process a discount
        intQtyToDiscount = intDiscountSwitch \ 5        'How many of the current item we need to discount
        intDiscountSwitch = intDiscountSwitch Mod 5     'Reset the discount switch to the remainder
        'First load the discounted items into the array
        arrBought(intItemCount, 0) = strItemID
        arrBought(intItemCount, 1) = curPrice * .8
        arrBought(intItemCount, 2) = intQtyToDiscount
        intItemCount = intItemCount + 1
    end if
    'Whether or not we had a discount, load the regular-priced items (intQtyToDiscount will be 0 if no discounted items)
    arrBought(intItemCount, 0) = strItemID
    arrBought(intItemCount, 1) = curPrice
    arrBought(intItemCount, 2) = intQtyBought - intQtyToDiscount
    RS.MoveNext
    intItemCount = intItemCount + 1
Loop
```